# How do I load a complete json object into a json column with bigquery.Client.load_table_from_uri()?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have json objects for loading as NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON in files. One object per line and I would like to ingest the complete object into a single column w type json? Current code below which loads each field into a column but instead of the SchemaField I would like something like a wildcard/alias for the complete object so I can load it into a single column? How can I do that?

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("userAgent", "STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("eventID", "STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("errorMessage", "STRING")],)

job = client.load_table_from_uri(uri, table, job_config=job_config)
```